# Multiple CSS page counters

Tags: html, css, pdf

I need to have more than one page counter on a PDF produced from an HTML document.

My document is 100 pages so I need a counter that counts from 1 to 100. I also have subsections within the document that need their own pages numbering say 1-10.  Imagine a book that has all pages numbered as well as each chapter having its own page numbers. Is this even possible?

I am using CSS Print media and can do the 1 to 100 counter but am stumped trying to get a second counter working.

Answer (score 4):

```html
<style>
  ul.not-working{
    counter-reset: volume;
    counter-reset: chapter;
  }

  ul li.volume:before{
    counter-increment: volume;
    content: "Volume " counter(volume) ": ";
  }
  ul li.chapter:before{
    counter-increment: chapter;
    content: "Volume " counter(chapter) ": ";
  }
</style>
<style>
  ul.working{
    counter-reset: volume chapter; /* all counters in same attributes */
  }

  ul li.volume:before{
    counter-increment: volume;
    content: "Volume " counter(volume) ": ";
  }
  ul li.chapter:before{
    counter-increment: chapter;
    content: "Volume " counter(chapter) ": ";
  }
</style>

<ul class="not-working">
  <li class='volume'>
    First Volume Name
    <ul>
      <li class='chapter'>First Chapter Name</li>
      <li class='chapter'>Second Chapter Name</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class='volume'>
    Second Volume Name
    <ul>
      <li class='chapter'>Third Chapter Name</li>
      <li class='chapter'>Fourth Chapter Name</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul class="working">
  <li class="volume">
    First Volume Name
    <ul>
      <li class="chapter">First Chapter Name</li>
      <li class="chapter">Second Chapter Name</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="volume">
    Second Volume Name
    <ul>
      <li class="chapter">Third Chapter Name</li>
      <li class="chapter">Fourth Chapter Name</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

source: https://www.rharriso.com/multiple-css-counters.html

Comment: ok I will do that then :) thanks for pointing that out to me!